# Laravel/PostgreSQL query with non-capitalised letters

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql

I am doing a Laravel CRUD exercise and I have set up a search route in the controller:

```
public function search($name)
    {
        return Product::where('name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')->get();
    }
```

And on the backend psql database, I have an item name exactly as `iPhone 11`.

When I ran a query on postman, it worked fine if I `GET` by `localhost:8000/api/products/search/iPh`. However, if I uncapitalised it as `...search/iph`, it would return an empty array.

So my question is, what do I do so I can search with uncapitalised letters while the data stored contains capitalised letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL you can use raw query

```
Product::whereRaw("UPPER(name) LIKE '%'". strtoupper($name)."'%'")->get();
```

For pgSQL you can use `ILIKE` for case in-sensitive and `LIKE` for case sensitive

```
Product::where('name', 'ILIKE', '%'.$name.'%')->get();
```

Comment: Good tip! Do you have any recommendation on a cheat sheet for this type of query for mysql and pgsql?

Comment: You can check Laravel Doc. There is not such kind of cheat sheet. Only few queries might not be compatible. You will find the solution for them easly.